# jenkins not able to build share extension ios xcode

Tags: ios, jenkins, ios-app-extension

I am getting following error while making build from jenkins.

```
 Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.company.xmessage.xmessageShareAction' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.company.xmessage.xmessageShareAction'.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'App Extension' in SDK 'iOS 11.3'
```

It build fine with xcode.

Comment: Do you have the provisioning profile and the certificate set in your XCode?

Comment: yes its build successfully when i build from xcode